# Postgresql how to return select as array

Tags: sql, postgresql

**IN POSTGRESQL:**

Say I have a table of `Users` and I do:

```
SELECT "EyeColor" FROM "Users" WHERE "Age" = 32
```

And this returns:

```
[
    {"EyeColor": "blue"},
    {"EyeColor": "green"},
    {"EyeColor": "blue"}
]
```

Then I want to put `blue, green, blue` into an array and use that. This is the closest I can get but it is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM "Eyes" WHERE "Color" IN
(SELECT array_agg("EyeColor") FROM "Users" WHERE "Age" = 32)
```

I want the anpve query to work the same as this:

```
SELECT * FROM "Eyes" WHERE "Color" IN ('blue', 'green')
```

Comment: So "Eyes" is json? And you want a json array or postgres array? Post an example of the desired output.

Comment: I edited the question, does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to aggregate the subquery result into an array. You can use [`IN (subquery)`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN)

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Eyes" 
WHERE "Color" IN (
    SELECT "Eyes" 
    FROM "Users" 
    WHERE "Age" = 32)
```

or [`ANY (subquery)`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Eyes" 
WHERE "Color" = ANY(
    SELECT "Eyes"
    FROM "Users" 
    WHERE "Age" = 32)
```

Comment: What, I tried exactly this many times without it working. Now that I tried it again just to double check, it works...thanks anyways haha!